# Load Mariadb files .frm .ibd .opt

Tags: database, mariadb

I recovered Mariadb files from a crashed server with *.frm*, *.ibd* and *.opt* extensions.
How can I "mount" them into a new database ? I saw [a way](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb#step-2-mdash-importing-a-mysql-or-mariadb-database) to do it with .sql files with something like `mysql -u username -p new_database < data-dump.sql`, but I don't know how to handle multiple files with this command.

Comment: Your answer is here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files

Comment: Oh thanks !! I didn't think to look on dba stackexchange !